# Swift - About importing packages vs classes

Tags: ios, swift3

I need to use MKMapViewDelegate in this class of mine, so I was wondering if it is a good practice to import

```
import MapKit.MKMapView
```

instead

```
import MapKit
```

Does importing whole package hit app performance or is there anything I should take into consideration in terms of performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import MapKit.MKMapView` makes no practical difference. It still imports all of `MapKit` (try creating an `MKShape()` for instance or any other MapKit class). Swift doesn't support importing individual classes this way. I don't know why it even allows the syntax (it may be worth opening a bug about that because it's confusing).

There are a small number of cases where there are actually sub-*modules*, and then you have to import the submodule directly (importing the umbrella isn't always good enough). For example, to get some category methods from SceneKit, you have to `import SceneKit.ModelIO` explicitly (but I expect this isn't really intended behavior, either).

But in any case, there isn't today a good reason to restrict your imports. Eventually, hopefully, Swift will get better importing capabilities that let us control our namespaces better, but for now, just import the module.

Answer (score 1):

No your app performance will not be impacted it is good practice to do either, however I would strong suggest just to import Mapkit, that way you may use anything within that import instead of importing multiple things from the same package.